# cmd to run exe not working from Python

Tags: python

consider portion of  Python code(Python 2.7) on Win 7 machine,

```
toolPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Target Compiler Technologies\\adsp2-12R2\\bin\\WINbin"
```

This is executed from python script under

> C:\dev\bin\toplevel\python

Now, I need to execute a command that runs(compiles and builds a DSP library, .prx is a project file for the library)
as

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Target Compiler
>   Technologies\adsp2-12R2\bin\WINbin\chessmk.exe
>   ".\..\..\..\dev\lib\adsp2\mylibs.prx -r -s

I am able to do that in cmd.exe shell as

```
%toolPath%\chessmk.exe "..\..\..\dev\lib\adsp2\mylibs.prx" -r -s
```

I can do the same in Python as

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Target Compiler Technologies\\adsp2-12R2\\bin\\WINbin\\chessmk.exe" "C:\\SVN\\ASROmni\\trunk1\\\dev\\lib\\adsp2\\mylibs.prx" -r'
subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
```

But, I have not been able to write similar code for Python, with relative paths and using *toolpath* variable.
for example,

```
cmd = 'toolPath+"\\chessmk.exe" ".\\..\\..\\..\\dev\\lib\\adsp2\\mylibs.prx" -r -s'
subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
```

gives error:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

following did not work too:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Target Compiler Technologies\\adsp2-12R2\\bin\\WINbin\\chessmk.exe" ".\\..\\..\\..\\dev\\lib\\adsp2\\mylibs.prx" -r'
subprocess.check_output(cmd,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
```

Update:
from one of the comments, I tried

```
cmd = os.path.join(toolPath,"chessmk.exe")+' C:\\SVN\\ASROmni\\trunk1\\\dev\\lib\\adsp2\\mylibs.prx -r'
```

it works,but the relative path one

```
cmd = os.path.join(toolPath,"chessmk.exe")+' .\\..\\..\\..\\dev\\lib\\adsp2\\mylibs.prx -r'
```

still dosn't.

any help.( This is my first day with python, so bear with me)
please note that the cmd should be run from within Python, not invoking shell=True.
Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be how you're passing the arguments to `check_output()`, try this instead:

```
toolPath = ('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Target Compiler Technologies\\'
            'adsp2-12R2\\bin\\WINbin\\chessmk.exe"')

cmd = [toolPath, '"..\..\..\dev\lib\adsp2\mylibs.prx"', '-r' '-s']

subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

However the relative path for the location of `mylibs.prx` may still be a problem. You might be able to make it work by calling [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=chdir#os.chdir) right before calling `check_output()`.

Comment: Hi Martineau, well %toolpath% was used as I could only create environment variables in shell. here,In python, toolpath is an ordinary variable, so, does it still need os.environ?

Comment: Using a relative path is making assumption about the current working directory. You can either change the cwd appropriately using `os.chdir()` before calling `check_output()` or pass the argument with an absolute path.

Comment: Hi martineau,  my bad, I was using extra // for relative path, so that is why it did not work. Now, It works. Thanks. One small query though, can i direct op of execution to STDOUT if not an error?

Comment: That good to hear. You don't need to do anything for it to go to stdout (that's the default).

Comment: I checked and the **subprocess.check** output only directs child process **stdout** to **stderror**, but when not in error, i should be able to see the message from child process(here, the DSP library that is executed)on sucess too, which i don't see .

Comment: The docs suggest using `subprocess.Popen` and its `communicate()` method when you need a `stderr` pipe.